# Linear Algebra, matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question 1.** Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear. Suppose that $T^3=T, T^2 \neq T, T^2 \neq Id,$ and $\dim \ker T = 2.$ Show that the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

*Attempt.* The first two columns of $0$s come from the fact that $\dim \ker T = 2.$ Furthermore, from the hypothesis, we have

$$0 = T(T-I)(T+I)$$

where $T(T-I), (T-I)(T+I), (T-I),(T+I) \neq 0$. How to continue from here? We need to show that $-1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: To clarify, minimal polynomial and Cayley-Hamilton are not necessary. This appears in introductory linear algebra course, and the technique of minimal polynomial hasn't been introduced.

Comment: What’s wrong with simply verifying that the given matrix satisfies the conditions? The way you’ve written the question here, you’re not being asked to derive the matrix.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. That is proving the converse.

Answer (score 5):

The polynomial $P = X^3-X  = (X-1)(X+1) X$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ of $T$.

More over, from the other hypotheses, $X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)$ and $X^2-X=(X-1) X$ are not divisible by $\mu_T$.

There is two options remaining:

- $\mu_T= X(X+1)(X-1)$ then $\dim(\ker(T))=1$.
- $\mu_T=X (X+1)$ so the only eigenvalues are $-1$ and $0$ and you can conclude from $\dim(\ker(T))$.

Comment: Clear and to the point answer, well done!

Comment: This is good. But can we come up with an answer that does not rely on the techniques of minimal polynomial? This question appears in an introductory linear algebra course and minimal polynomial is not introduced.

Answer (score 1):

$$ T(T-I)(T+I) =0 \implies \lambda (\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)=0 $$

Where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of your matrix.

Upon the orthogonal diagonalization you will find a  diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the main diagonal.

The set of eigenvectors associated with this matrix constitute the desired basis for the space.

Comment: This explanation is not clear to me. Your first implication as currently written down is wrong. Moreover, the fact that $T(T-I)(T+I)=0$ only says that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)=0$. Only looking at this, it's possible that $\lambda=1$ is the only eigenvalue. Thus, this equation alone is not very useful.

Comment: Does Cayley Hamilton Theorem help?

Comment: I know how to solve the exercise, I'm just explaining that I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are given that $T(T-I)(T+I)=0$, $T(T-I)\ne 0$ and $(T-I)(T+I)\ne 0$.

- Because $T(T-I)\ne 0$ and $(T+I)T(T-I)=0$, then $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
- Because $(T-I)(T+I)\ne 0$ and $T(T-I)(T+I)=0$, then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

The dimension of $\mbox{ker}(T)$ is $2$, which forces the dimension of $\mbox{ker}(T+I)$ to be $1$, because the space is 3-dimensional and $\mbox{ker}(T+I)\ne \{0\}$. So $T$ is diagonalizable with eignevalues $0,0,-1$.